# GPO applied on windows server 2008 r2 x64 system itself, no program could open or run

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

Hope you are good. I set Group policy for users but accidentally it is applied on **server itself**. Now no GPO or Active Directory or GPMC is opening in Windows Server 2008 R2 system. When i try to open it says "could not open due to restrictions in effect of this computer. Please contact your system administrator".  Unable to Open GPMC OR boot in Safe mode so i can reset it. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable problem GPO

1. Found your problem GPO ID.
   You can use powershell `get-gpo -all | select Displayname,Id | ft` to get list all domain GPO and it's id,

or browse with ADSIEdit `CN=Policies,CN=System` in domain root to search Policy ID by **displayName** (not an easy task when has many policies).

With ADSIEdit you can connect even with a computer is not a domain member. On such a computer certainly not applyed problem policy.

2. Browse with ADSIEdit `CN=Policies,CN=System` in domain root to search Policy by ID, and set it's **flag** attribute to `3` - [mean GPO disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh455118.aspx).
3. Perform refresh group policy (`gpupdate /force` or reboot)

Comment: Dear Slipeer! thanks for reply. I tried to open PowerShell but it says "this operations has'n cancelled due to restrictions in effect of this computer. Please......" as i told the "Run these specified programs only" GP applied on "Admin Tools-->System-->Run these......." on server 2008 R2 itself. What to do as all and every option is locked through GP.

Comment: With ADSIEdit you can connect even with a computer is not a domain member. On such a computer certainly not applyed problem policy.